# how to delete the space if argument is empty

Tags: spacing, macros, expex

I made a `\newcommand` for my glossed examples using `ExPex` package, that looks like this :

```
\newcommand{\exgl}[6]{\ex\label{#1}\begingl\glpreamble \tt #2// \gla #3// \glb #4// \glft #5 // \endgl \begin{flushright}(#6)\end{flushright}\xe}
```

The `#5` argument is the translation and there are some examples that I don't need to translate. If I leave the argument empty LaTeX still leaves the space for it. How can I formulate the order that delete this space IF the argument in the `\newcommand` is empty??

Pretty pleasy :)

Comment: Use `\usepackage{etoolbox}` in the preamble and `\ifblank{#5}{}{\glft #5}` at the appropiate position in the command, for example. And please post working examples, not only fragments of code

Comment: By the way: `\tt` is deprecated for `LaTeX` for 20 years now. Use `\texttt{...}` instead. As well: `\RaggedRight` etc. is better than `flushleft`

Comment: @Christian Hupfer Thank you! that works just fine!! :)

Answer (score 4):

Since there are some commands using `expex` package I don't understand I provided some dummy commands.

The relevant question is the argument `#5`, which can be empty. One solution is to use `\ifblank{}` from `etoolbox` or an optional argument, best defining the command with `\NewDocumentCommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% A lot of dummy commands

\providecommand{\ex}{}
\providecommand{\xe}{}


\newenvironment{gl}{}{}


\providecommand{\glpreamble}{}%

\providecommand{\gla}[1]{#1}%
\providecommand{\glb}[1]{#1}%
\providecommand{\glft}[1]{\Large\textbf{#1}}%


\usepackage{ragged2e} % For \RaggedRight
\usepackage{etoolbox} % For \ifblank{#5}{true}{false}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\exgl}[6]{\ex\label{#1}\begin{gl}\glpreamble \texttt{#2}// \gla{#3}// \glb{#4}//\ifblank{#5}{}{\glft{#5}//} \end{gl}\RaggedRight(#6)\xe}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\exglenhanced}{mmmmom}{\ex\label{#1}\begin{gl}\glpreamble \texttt{#2}// \gla{#3}// \glb{#4}//\IfValueT{#5}{\glft{#5}//} \end{gl}\RaggedRight(#6)\xe}

\begin{document}
\noindent\exgl{foo}{This Is}{Some}{Command}{}{I don't understand}


\exgl{foocmd}{This Is}{Some}{Command}{which}{I don't understand}

Now with \verb+\exglenhanced+ and optional argument:

\exglenhanced{fooother}{This Is}{Some}{Command}{I don't understand}

\exglenhanced{fooothercmd}{This Is}{Some}{Command}[which]{I don't understand}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't recommend such a pile up of arguments in a command at all!

Comment: I've incorporated the last `//` pair into the `\ifblank` stuff, if this is not correct, it should be placed outside

Comment: oh, yeah, I just undesrtood what you ment. Yes I've incorporated the // into \ifblank environement and it's perfect!